# How does springboot @PathVariable get Chinese parameters in the path

Tags: java, spring-boot, http, spring-mvc

In the development of springboot project, a requirement needs to forward the error Chinese information string to the corresponding controller for processing, so I first use urlencoder Encode (message, "UTF-8"), then splice the encoded string to the URL, and use httpservletresponse.Sendredirect("url") redirects to the target controller with the following code:

```
    private void responseError(ServletResponse response, String message) {
        try {
            HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
            message = URLEncoder.encode(message, "UTF-8");
            httpServletResponse.sendRedirect("/unauthorized/" +  message);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

In the controller, use @Requestmapping(value = "/unauthorized/{message}") to get the dynamic parameter message on the path. The code is as follows:

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/unauthorized/{message}")
    public ResultMap unauthorized(@PathVariable("message") String message){
        return ResultMap.fail(message);
    }
```

During the test, it is found that the encoded Chinese string is similar to the form of %E7%99%BB%E5%BD%95%E8%Ba%AB%E4%BB%BD%E5%A4%B1%E6%95%88. During redirection, the request keeps cycling. The controller cannot capture the request, and finally reports an error: exceeded maxredirects Probably stuck in a redirect loop.
However, after I remove % from the parameter string, the controller method can capture and process the request normally. Therefore, I guess @Requestmapping() cannot match the special character %. Does anyone have a solution?